# The non-generic type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' cannot be used with type arguments

Tags: c#, .net, generics, queue, nodes

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public sealed class LoLQueue<T> where T: class
{
    private SingleLinkNode<T> mHe;
    private SingleLinkNode<T> mTa;

    public LoLQueue()
    {
        this.mHe = new SingleLinkNode<T>();
        this.mTa = this.mHe;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
The non-generic type 'LoLQueue<T>.SingleLinkNode' cannot be used with type arguments
```

Why do i get this?

Comment: What is your definition of SingleLinkNode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you haven't defined your `SingleLinkNode` class as having a generic type parameter. As such, an attempt to declare it with one is failing.

The error message suggests that `SingleLinkNode` is a nested class, so I suspect what may be happening is that you are declaring members of `SingleLinkNode` of type `T`, without actually declaring `T` as a generic parameter for `SingleLinkNode`. You still need to do this if you want `SingleLinkNode` to be generic, but if not, then you can simply use the class as `SingleLinkNode` rather than `SingleLinkNode<T>`.

Example of what I mean:

```
public class Generic<T> where T : class
{
    private class Node
    {
        public T data; // T will be of the type use to construct Generic<T>
    }

    private Node myNode;  // No need for Node<T>
}
```

If you *do* want your nested class to be generic, then this will work:

```
public class Generic<T> where T : class
{
    private class Node<U>
    {
        public U data; // U can be anything
    }

    private Node<T> myNode;  // U will be of type T
}
```

Answer (score 31):

If you want to use `IEnumerable<T>`, as your post's title suggests, you need to include `using System.Collections.Generic;`.

As for the SingleLinkNode class, I don't know where you got it, it's not part of the .NET framework that I can see. I'd guess that it isn't implemented using generics, and you'll need to add a bunch of casts from `object` to `T` everywhere.

Comment: He already has that listed on the **first line** of his code.

Comment: True, but considering the title of this question is "The non-generic type System.Collections.IEnumerable", I assumed that something changed in the copy-paste of code.

Comment: This solved the problem for me, but I don't know why I only needed this on one server and not the others that I put it on.  Is there some defaults that are set at a server level somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

This compiles for me:

```
public sealed class SingleLinkNode<T>
{

}

public sealed class LoLQueue<T> where T : class
{
    private SingleLinkNode<T> mHe;
    private SingleLinkNode<T> mTa;

    public LoLQueue()
    {
        this.mHe = new SingleLinkNode<T>();
        this.mTa = this.mHe;
    }
}
```

You'll need to post your SingleLinkNode class for further answers...

John